# "Cannot reference Employee.DEFAULT_GENDER before supertype constructor has been called" Error

Tags: java, constructor

I have the following code

```
public class Employee {

private String name;
private String gender;
private int age;

final String DEFAULT_GENDER = "male";
final int DEFAULT_AGE = 18;

public Employee(String name,String gender,int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
}

public Employee(String name) {
    this(name,DEFAULT_GENDER,DEFAULT_AGE);
}

}
```

I am getting the following error

```
Cannot reference Employee.DEFAULT_GENDER before supertype constructor has been called
```

I don't understand why is it saying `Employee.DEFAULT_GENDER`? I have not defined it as static! and why is it not allowing me to call the constructor with 3 parameters? I have defined `DEFAULT_GENDER` and `DEFAULT_AGE` to ensure some default values. All you need to create an Employee object is his name(gender and age is set to default in that case. Also no default constructor allowed). Any views as of why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFAULT_GENDER` is an instance variable of the class `Employee`, it cannot be used until an instance of the class is created. Until the constructor executes completely the instance is not fully constructed, hence you get such an error.

Make both the default values as `static` .

```
final static String DEFAULT_GENDER = "male";
final static int DEFAULT_AGE = 18;
```

Qualifying the variables as `static` makes them associated with the class `Employee` and hence it can exist without creating any instance of the class `Employee`.

Comment: Would making it static solve the problem? static variables are initialized when class is loaded.

Comment: @AniketThakur this answer is correct, make them static they belong to the class rather to object +1

Comment: Great thanks. that worked but just out of curiosity is there a work around if I want default values on object level rather that Class level?

Comment: @AniketThakur What does default value on object level means ?

Comment: Lets say I have a field called initialDesignation which will depend on   which university the employee is hired from. So each object will have this default  initialDesignation depending on university he is from(this data can be retrieved from db and initialDesignation can be decided accordingly on object level).

Comment: Then you need some sort of static final `Map` containing `<university,initialDesignation>` and use that in your constructor which just accepts `university` .

Answer (score 0):

You can make it static if you want to be able to get it anywhere 
but used the first answer make a new instance as a better design